# How can I get rid of PDF startxref error and AbstractRenderer warning messages when generating PDF documents and then merging it using iText 7?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using iText version 7.1.6 to generate PDF documents and in the end I am trying to merge it.

Below is the code used for merging along with comments.

```java
List<byte[]> pdfDocumentList= new ArrayList<byte[]>();

// pdfDocumentList has list of byte arrays generated from other ways
ByteArrayOutputStream mergeOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfMerged = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergeOutputStream));
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfMerged);
ByteArrayOutputStream finalOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(finalOutputStream);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

// sb is containing the concatenated HTML sources
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(sb.toString(), pdf, properties);
pdf.close();
pdfDocumentList.add(finalOutputStream.toByteArray());
if(!pdfDocumentList.isEmpty()){
    for(byte[] bytes : pdfDocumentList){
        PdfDocument externalPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
        merger.merge(externalPdf, 1, externalPdf.getNumberOfPages());
    }
}
pdfMerged.close();
return mergeOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

When I am merging the list of PDF documents, I get the below error and warning. In *addition*, the warning keeps getting printed multiple times. How can I fix it?

#### Warning

```
WARNING: The background rectangle has negative or zero sizes. It will not be displayed.
Jul 18, 2019 2:24:24 PM com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer drawBackground
```

#### Error

```
<Jul 18, 2019, 2:27:19,964 PM AST> <Error> <com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader> <BEA-000000> <Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF startxref not found.
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.getStartxref(PdfTokenizer.java:262)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:753)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:538)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1818)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:238)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
2019-07-18 14:27:19 ERROR user: KALASINX ip: 127.0.0.1 (ServiceInterceptor.java:59) ~ ServiceInterceptor Error:
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Trailer not found.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.rebuildXref(PdfReader.java:1064) ~[kernel-7.1.6.jar:?]
```

Comment: You comment *"pdfDocumentList has list of byte arrays generated from other ways"* - have you tried without those *byte arrays generated from other ways*? Probably they are broken, causing iText to fail merging all these PDFs...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Actually the scenario is i have 10 HTML sources. Out of these 7 does not contain SVG elements in them. 3 of them contain. I am using Itext Api's HTMLConverter.convertToPdf() method to generate PDF. This method is not generating the PDF properly for the HTML's containing SVG elements .So, I am generating the PDF's separately for those 3 HTML's containing SVG elements and then trying to merge with the PDF generated using those 7 HTML sources. I could not find other ways. Can you suggest any other alternative if you are aware ?

Comment: Please share examples for those byte arrays for analysis. According to the exception text, those PDFs appear to have issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will share them. Actually I forgot to mention in my previous reply that out of the 3 HTML's containing SVG elements, I said I am generating PDF's separately. For one HTML containing SVG element, I am generating multiple PDF's and storing them at some physical location and merging them. The final merge of all PDF's includes the merged PDF. Only this merged PDF is giving the issue. I was wondering if we can merge the PDF which was generated by merging with other PDF's. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: How do you merge them?

Comment: Suppose, If the HTML has 2 SVG elements, I am creating 3 PDF files. one for HTML and 2 for SVG. Then i iterate all the three and use PdfMerger.merge() method to merge them.

Comment: Ok,  `PdfMerger.merge()` is a good option. Probably a look at the byte arrays will help.

Comment: You are right :) . Looks like the byte arrays were corrupted. I used List of ByteArrayOutputStream and then finally merged them. It worked.

Comment: If you don't mind, Can you please help me with this font issue for SVG using IText here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921868/external-font-is-not-getting-applied-to-svg-content-inside-html-after-it-gets-ge

Comment: I haven't yet played around with svg and itext. I'll take a look next week anyways, though.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thank you for your usual support as always :)

Comment: Btw in the above question, I have mentioned the WARNING message which i keep getting when generating PDF. Do you have any idea how to get rid of this ?

Comment: *"Do you have any idea how to get rid of this ?"* - no. I'd assume those are due to some degenerate html structures, e.g. a div with zero height or width and a fill color. In that case you'd merely need to clean the html. But this is merely an assumption.

Comment: ok i got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the HTML code and with repeated testing, I was able to get rid of the warning message. I had to remove the **background-color** style in the CSS of the HTML that was related to
the *table*, *tr*, and *td* tags.